# Cannot write to sqlite3 in docker container

Tags: django, linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am starting to get my feet wet attempting to deploy a django/react app up on an EC2 instance.  Everything is running fine on my personal Windows computer but when I pulled the code into the Ubuntu 22.04.3 container I got the following error:

`django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations table (attempt to write a readonly database)`

As I said this worked fine on my Windows laptop but is not working in Linux.  Is this an issue with Linux or my Dockerfile?  I plan to eventually use a postgres instance once I am feeling confident, but maybe I should just do it?

**Dockerfile:**

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9-slim-bullseye
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION} as python


# Stage1:  Create Wheels
FROM python as python-build-stage
ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local

# required for make and setup for postgres (not used yet)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
   build-essential \
   libpq-dev


COPY Backend/requirements .
 
RUN pip wheel --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels \
   -r ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# Stage 2:  Setup Django
FROM python as python-run-stage

ARG BUILD_ENVIRONMENT=local
ARG APP_HOME=/app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ENV BUILD_ENV ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

RUN addgroup --system django \
    && adduser --system --ingroup django django

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    libpq-dev \
    netcat \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=python-build-stage /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --no-index --find-links=/wheels/ /wheels/* \
   && rm -rf /wheels/

# django app 
COPY --chown=django:django ./Webserver/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY --chown=django:django ./Webserver/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY --chown=django:django . ${APP_HOME}

RUN chown django:django ${APP_HOME}

USER django

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

**entrypoint:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset

exec "$@"
```

**Start:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit
set -o pipefail
set -o nounset
 
python3 Backend/manage.py migrate --no-input
python3 Backend/manage.py collectstatic --no-input
sudo python3 Backend/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
# sudo gunicorn finalstrip.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000  --timeout 600
```

Comment: SQLite in a container can be hard to manage in a couple of ways, and using a separate database container is usually better practice.  It will resolve the specific issue you're having here and I would suggest just doing that.

Comment: I agree it will be better practice to have a separate database but I don't understand why.  This seems like something that could bite me later because I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Managing the file permissions is surprisingly tricky, but the standard Docker Hub database images know how to do it.  If you ever want to run more than one copy of your container, or use a clustered environment like Kubernetes, using a local-file-backed data store will cause trouble, but again you can have multiple connections from across the cluster to a relational-database container.